# GWT using Activities and Places when screen layout changes per place

Tags: gwt, gwt-activities, gwt-places

My understanding of GWT's Activities and Places is that for a given region on a screen you have an `ActivityManager` and an `ActivityMapper`. You can have multiple regions on the screen which means you can have multiple `ActivityManagers` and `ActivityMappers` (one per region). So, whenever there is a `PlaceChange` the `ActivityManagers` ask their respective `ActivityMapper` what activity it is supposed to be showing given the `Place`. This works great as long as your `Places` all have a common layout that they reuse in different ways to perform different activities. My question is how do we handle the case where different `Places` use radically different layouts? My first thought is to just have even more `ActivityManagers` and `ActivityMappers`, if the `Place` doesn't use a particular region then the `ActivityMapper` for that region will simply return `null` when we change to that `Place`. If there is a better way I would appreciate any wisdom.

Comment: I don't think there's a _better_ way. See http://tbroyer.posterous.com/gwt-21-activities-nesting-yagni

Comment: Thank you, that article was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I found it much easier to use a single ActivityMapper/ActivityManager pair for the entire app.

In a typical case you have a "menu" region and a "main" region. The menu region is very basic: a click on a menu item sends a user to a new place. It also highlights the newly selected item and resets the style of the previously selected item. All of this can be easily done in a simple widget that you can include in all views where this menu is required. Having separate ActivityMapper and ActivityManager for the menu region just complicates everything without providing any benefits.

I use the same approach for "top menu" region and "left menu/tree" region: a widget that tells the presenter which data to show in the "main" region.

I have over 50 different places in my app, and it really helps to have a simple architecture: each place corresponds to one view and one activity.

Comment: Do you make a point of avoiding multiple Activities for a single Place so that you can use that structure or do you have some way of still supporting multiple Activities while using a single ActivityManager/ActivityMapper?

Comment: I avoid using multiple activities. I never encountered a UI design where two regions are simultaneously involved in a kind of complex and independent behavior that warrants a dedicated activity per region. I guess such designs are possible, but I believe that creating a dedicated activity for a menu or a tree creates more problems that it solves.